# Entity framework code first object references multiple objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

For a school assignment I want to make a small questionaire-type of website where you can input several questions and add them to an exam.

The technologies I use are MVC and Entity Framework (code first). For both it is the first time I am riding on my own, without tutorials and such and I seem to have gotten stuck in my model-design (those that will be used for the database).

I want an `Exam`table which holds several `Questions`. This, to my understanding, should be a collection (research said to use this, but I am unsure this is correct).

How would I set the `Exam` model in this case, so that it holds multiple `Question objects` and can also be used by Entity Frameworks' Code First?

Here is what I have now:

```
public class Exam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public enum Answers
    {
        A,
        B,
        C,
        D
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AnswerA { get; set; }
    public string AnswerB { get; set; }
    public string AnswerC { get; set; }
    public string AnswerD { get; set; }
    public Answers Correct { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What you have looks fine, what problem are you having?

Comment: This seems correct. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Have you created your context and tried to use the above entities? It all looks ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want add to your Question properties like this:

```
[ForeignKey("Exam")]
public int ExamId { get; set; }

public virtual Exam Exam { get; set; }
```

if you want to have control over foregin keys.

And you can add virtual keyword to enable lazy loading in your Exam class:

```
public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
```